# `wkhtmltox` behaviour varies in AWS Lambda to Mac

Tags: python, css, macos, aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf

I have been using the [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) package to convert html to pdf. This works more or less fine on my computer (Mac) but in AWS Lambda some CSS styling is ignored. The problem seems to mainly be with my tables - they no longer have any margins and the styles applied to `<td>` and `<th>` elements is no longer applied. As far as I can tell, the versions are both the same (`0.12.6`). I am installing the package to my Lambda as a layer downloaded from [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

The code to do the conversion is this:

```
options = {
        # "page-size": "Letter",
        "margin-top": "0",
        "margin-right": "0",
        "margin-bottom": "0",
        "margin-left": "0",
        "encoding": "UTF-8",
        "no-outline": True,
        "enable-local-file-access": True,
    }

with open(html_path) as f:
    # wkhtmltopdf is installed in different locations on lambda and local. This
    # allows it to run in both envs
    if os.getenv("WK_PATH") == "local":
        pdfkit.from_file(
            f,
            pdf_path,
            options=options,
        )
    else:
        PDFKIT_CONFIG = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf")
        pdfkit.from_file(
            f,
            pdf_path,
            options=options,
            configuration=PDFKIT_CONFIG,
        )
```

You can see when running in a lambda I have to provide the path to the library, but nothing else changes. Styling is applied via CSS to an html file which is then converted to PDF using the above code.

Has anyone seen this problem before or have any suggestions for workarounds? I can only assume the lambda layer differs from the mac version, but this is quite a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that:

- The `options` variable was overwriting anywhere in the css with matching names. i.e `margin-right` was always being set to 0.
- Colours using the `rgb` function didnt work, I had to use the hex code instead

Just putting this here in case someone makes same mistake as I did!